# Are there education tests other than PISA test to compare education performance among countries?

Tags: education

When comparing the education level and performance among countries, the media tends to like to use the PISA test. Are there any education tests other than PISA that compare educational performance among countries?

*I don't mind, if exists, in higher education level or specific industries. If they could compare the education among countries.*

Comment: There are a few as seen in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_rankings#Education_and_innovation) under *Education and innovation*.

Comment: @Panda Do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I've elaborated on the notable ones in my answer.

Comment: This question seems like a better fit for [SE.Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @nat I am looking at the society side of the educational tests, Academia SE is more like discussing the academia itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few other notable education performance indices.

The International Association for the Evaluation of Educational Achievement (IEA) publishes the [Progress in International Reading Literacy Study](http://www.iea.nl/pirls). It's cited [by The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/answer-sheet/wp/2017/03/06/what-the-numbers-really-tell-us-about-americas-public-schools/?utm_term=.4e47e42c4b9b) as an example of an international test.

> PIRLS provides **internationally comparative data on how well children read by assessing students’ reading achievement**. PIRLS collects considerable background information on how education systems provide educational opportunities to their students, as well as the factors that influence how students use these opportunities.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> <sup>Source: http://www.iea.nl/pirls</sup>

There's also the [Trends in International Mathematics and Science Study](http://www.iea.nl/timss) which is published also by IEA and it's cited as another example of an international test by The Washington Post and [also by Brookings Institute](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/brown-center-chalkboard/2017/04/07/what-international-test-scores-reveal-about-american-education/) and [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2016/nov/29/english-pupils-improve-results-in-international-maths-and-science-exams).

> TIMSS has been **measuring trends in mathematics and science achievement at the fourth and eighth grades** since 1995. Conducted every four years at the fourth and eighth grades, TIMSS has a quasi-longitudinal design, with the fourth grade student cohort assessed four years later at the eighth grade.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> <sup>Source: http://www.iea.nl/timss</sup>

[Wikipedia has some other rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_rankings#Education_and_innovation) regarding "education and innovation" but most are mainly about literacy rates.